# pg_connect or PDO

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

My first project with PHP and postgreSQL, I have a good experience in MSSQL and ASP.
I was run test connections with pg_connect and PDO and everything was OK, making some test with a 3000 rows resultsets I was encounter that pg_connect have is at least 20% more speed than PDO.
In other hand I see most people use PDO, why?
In your opinion what are the pros and cons for each one?
Thank's.

Comment: See [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: You should clarify, whether or not your tests run under the same circumstances, which sadly includes nearly every default setting of both interfaces. The 30% appears slightly too much (not saying, that one may not be faster than the other).

Comment: @vanneto sorry, I ask because is a practical problem, I need to choose and many experienced people here can have the key for that decision.

Comment: @KingCrunch, I'm running the defaults installation of PHP and postgreSQL in my machine, your are right I repeat the test many times and never reach 30%, but is never under 14% and usually is around 22%. I will check if some missconfiguration. Thanks.

Comment: See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384224/pdo-vs-pg-functions)

Comment: @HMarioD And this is only the time for `connect()` (or similar)? hmm... 20% sounds a little bit more realistic :) But I guess we are talking about very small values?

Comment: @KingCrunch is the time for all, connection and retrieve the data, and yes there are small values ~600ms. But in my app. the response time is critical. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are comfortable with object-oriented programming, I would recommend PDO. For most projects that feature a reasonable amount of database interaction, you would probably want to use a wrapper class for your *_connect functions anyway. PDO eliminates this need since you are using objects already.

Also, PDO has convenient methods for prepared statements, which is a secure way to insert / update data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I think I may use both because some "pages" are actually services and need to give very quick responses, and other are regular pages.